# How do I get the type of the executing Controller in MVC .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my own DI I am trying to fork code based on whether the current request is executing in the context of an anoymous request or not. I guessed the easiest way would be to infer the type of the current controller and see if it was a subtype of our own anonymous api controller:

```cs
public bool InAnonymousContext() {
  var anonymousContext = false;
  if (_actionContextAccessor?.ActionContext != null)
  {
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(_actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);

    var type = controllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo?.GetType();
                
    anonymousContext = type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractAnonymousApiController)) ?? false;
  }

  return anonymousContext;
}
```

but I've made a wrong assumption that `IActionContextAccessor` would be available to me from DI.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found meta data on the `HttpContext` via DI & `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
var ctx = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();    
var action = ctx.HttpContext?.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();    
var type = action?.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType();
if (type != null && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractAnonymousApiController)))
  return null;
```